# sftp refused on Debian machines

Tags: debian, sftp

in my LAN there are different OS for testing purposes. All of the machines do not have any iptables or firewalling since it is only for testing. I am facing an issue with sftp lately. I cannot connect to any Debian machine from win7 using winscp! It comes with an error stating `Received too large (538975067 B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 1024000 B... Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?..`
The thing is that putty can connect through ssh to these machines and login as root, but not winscp. 
I reinstalled openssh-server in all of the Debian machines, but nothing changed.

Comment: Versions of the software involved (i.e. winscp and sshd)?

Comment: winscp is 5.11.3. All systems are Debian 9.3. How can i see sshd version?

Answer (score 0):

```
Received too large (538975067 B) SFTP packet.
```

Something on the remote system is causing it to send data through the ssh connection which isn't part of the SFTP protocol. A likely explanation is that there is a command in the remote user's `.bashrc` file (or some similar shell startup file) which is producing output. Your sftp client is expecting to read a message from the remote sftp server, but it's getting this other data instead.

538975067 translates to 20201B5B hexadecimal, which represents the characters " ", " ", "[", and ESC (space, space, left bracket, ESCape). The remote command may be trying to print an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to set the text color or something like that.

SFTP creates a non-interactive session on the remote system; notably, the process running on the remote system won't have a [TTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTY). You need to check the remote system, figure out what command is producing this output for SSH connections, and prevent that from happening for non-interactive sessions.

Comment: issue has been tracked down to the .bashrc. It has an entry for the screenfetch program to show the status of the system. It has been commented out and the sftp issue has been sorted out.